# openssl-1.0.1f msys/mingw64 build fail

Tags: build, openssl, configure, msys, mingw-w64

I am getting an error building openssl-1.0.1f with msys/mingw64:

```
installing libcrypto.a
/bin/sh: line 5: mingw64bin/ranlib.exe: No such file or directory
installing libssl.a
/bin/sh: line 5: mingw64bin/ranlib.exe: No such file or directory
make: *** [install_sw] Error 1
```

when I run .Configure I get:

```
ENGINES_OBJ   =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =\mingw64\bin/ranlib.exe
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =perl
```

Soooooo seems pretty easy I just need to change the backslashes to slashes

I open .Configure and search for Ranlib and I get:

```
my $ranlib = $ENV{'RANLIB'} || $fields[$idx_ranlib];
```

Farther down:

```
\$\(CROSS_COMPILE\)$cc/;
s/^AR=\s*/AR= \$\(CROSS_COMPILE\)/;
s/^NM=\s*/NM= \$\(CROSS_COMPILE\)/;
s/^RANLIB=\s*/RANLIB= \$\(CROSS_COMPILE\)/;
```

Oookkeeee why not change \s*/RANLIB= \$(CROSS_COMPILE)/; to \s*/RANLIB= /$/(CROSS_COMPILE)/;

```
Scalar found where operator expected at ./Configure line 1619, near "s/^RANLIB=\s*/RANLIB= /$/"
Backslash found where operator expected at ./Configure line 1619, near "CROSS_COMPILE\"
syntax error at ./Configure line 1619, near "s/^RANLIB=\s*/RANLIB= /$/"
Execution of ./Configure aborted due to compilation errors.
```

How I feel:

http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/234/765/b7e.jpg

For those still wondering, yes I am a beginner.

Soooo my questions:

Is ranlib path the real problem here? If so, how can I make msys see slashes instead of backslashes? If you know the answer, do you think you can use concise and clear explanations?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to build OpenSSL not from the MSYS console.

You should run these commands from the MSYS console (to start it, use `C:\msys64\msys.bat`):

```
perl Configure mingw64 --prefix=/wherever-you-need-to-put-it
make
make test
make install
```

P.S. MSYS should be configured for using MinGW: you should create a file C:\msys64\etc\fstab with a line like this (adjust the first part if it is different on your machine).

```
c:/mingw64      /mingw
```

Comment: I was trying to build from inside the Msys console.  As it turns out, I installed the msys perl and erased strawberries perl from my machine.  And it did the job!

Ssooo I guess it was only a configuration thingy...